# Add Javascript Variable To End Of Link

Tags: jquery, variables, hyperlink, append

I am trying to create a hyperlink based on the location that is sent to me.

for example:

var **location** = 12345 stackoverflow drive

html code:

```
<div id="add"></div>
```

js:

```
$('#add').append('<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q= **location** >Click</a>');
```

However, this link does not take me to the variable location, it actually searches the word "location"
How would I fix this?

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LPZsA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation since `location` is a variable

```
$('#add').append('<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=' + location + '">Hello</a>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KEEy7/)